# How run makemigrations <app> --empty with Django and Docker?

Tags: django, docker

I have a Django app with Docker and Docker-compose.

So I can build, up or down my container but how can I run `manage.py or django-admin` command like  `makemigrationn <app> --empty` ?

In a "classical" Django project architecture, no problem

But using Docker, I have an error
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting STATIC_URL, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

I try `django-admin makemigrations myapp --empty --settings=core.settings.dev` but have another error `no module core found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when you have a Django app using docker-compose, you need to issue the command to the correct service/container. If you have a `db` service and a `web` service in your compose file, and the `web` service is the Django app, you would do something like:

`docker-compose exec web python manage.py makemigrations`